# For loops while i>10 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, for-loop, iterator

To set `i` and its maximum and have a double iterator In Java, I would use `for` loops as follows:

```
for (i=1; i<10, i+=){
   for (j=1; j<10; j++){
      puts i (or whatever function)
   }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Ruby. The `for` loops I've seen in Ruby are for ranges, and single iterator:

```
for i in (1..10)
  puts i
end
```

or `while` loops

```
i = 1
while i < 10
  puts i
  i += 1
end
```

Are these `while` loops the (single iterator) Ruby equivalent of the Java I mentioned, or is there another way to do these `for` loops?

Comment: first result 'looping in ruby' http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm.  Note that searching for basic information is always faster than posting a question and waiting for an answer.

Comment: Your code suggests you want to do `i < 10` but your title suggests you want to do `i > 10`. Don't put a misleading/unrelated title.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I had looked, but I chose to use StackOverflow because the goal was to asked skilled programmers "Is there a better way" and to hopefully see examples that help me understand.  The question accomplished that, sorry if you were inconvenienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ruby-ish" way would be `each`

```
(1...10).each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

or to double iterate

```
(1...10).each do 
  (1...10).each do |j|
    puts j
  end
end
```

As @maxwilliams and @sawa point out, `(1...10)` is 1 through 9 inclusive, `(1..10)` is 1 through 10 inclusive.

Comment: This is the cleanest i think.  His loops only go from 1 to 9, though, in his original question.  BTW you missed out the ` |i|` in your second example.

Comment: @MaxWilliams well spotted, I guess I should've done (1...10), I'll edit it.  I left out the `i` deliberately... I didn't need the variable as I was just outputting `j`

Answer (score 1):

Why not do a nested loop?

```
for i in 1...10
  for j in 1...10
    puts i
  end
end
```

By the way, the Ruby equivalent is `for i in 1...10`, not `for i in 1..10`.

Comment: Source for `1...10` as opposed to `1..10`? The results I've seen don't support that.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you rarely use the `for` loop. Actually, you never use it. In Ruby you use enumerators and blocks.

```
for (i=1; i<10, i+=){
   for (j=1; j<10; j++){
      puts i (or whatever function)
   }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
(1...10).each do |i|
  (1...10).each do |j|
    puts j
  end
end
```

Also note there is a difference between

```
(1..10).each do |i|
end
```

and

```
(1...10).each do |i|
end
```

The latter is equivalent to

```
(1..9).each do |i|
end
```

In fact, the `..` will create an inclusive range whereas `...` an exclusive range.

It is also worth to mention that in Ruby you rarely use indexes to loop items. Therefore, if your goal is to print out some elements in an array, your code should not be

```
(1..10).each do |i|
  p @items[i]
end
```

rather you call each on the collection.

```
@items.each do |item|
  p item
end
```

In certain cases, like in your question, you don't even need a range (when your loop starts from 1. You can use `times`.

```
9.times do |i|
  9.times do |j|
    puts j
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

In Ruby we don't use parenthesis. They are uncool.

This is an example for `while` statement in Ruby

```
while $i < $num  do
   puts "Value for i is #{i}"
   $i +=1
end
```

And this is an example for `for` loop.

```
for i in 0..10
   puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

But there are more loops! Check this for more info http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

But if you are Java programmer, you can check this link https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-java/